# MS Access SQL multiple JOIN and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, where-clause, parentheses

I am attempting to join multiple tables onto a master table called 'Claims' (code below)
Three tables have the following conditions

1. [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12] has duplicate keys and must select the correct record where the value in the master table is between two dates in the lookup table
2. [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13] has duplicate keys and must select the correct record where the value in the master table is between two dates in the lookup table
3. [NY Medicare] has duplicate keys and must look at 'Zone' as a second level to select the correct record

When I am only using one WHERE clause the query works and there are no issues.  Adding 1 or two additional WHERE conditions for separate tables causes trouble.

I have researched a great deal on the internet and found that **Parenthesis** matter a great deal for ACCESS.  I see examples on proper syntax for multiple joins, but not multiple joins with WHERE clauses for specific tables.

I hope I am just misunderstanding how to place the parenthesis.

---

```
FROM ( ( ( ( ( ( [Claims]  
LEFT JOIN [BillType] ON [Claims].[Bill_Type] = [BillType].[BillType_Bill Type Key] )  
LEFT JOIN [PlaceofService] ON [Claims].[Place_of_Service] = [PlaceofService].[POS_Place of Service] )  
LEFT JOIN [Participating] ON [Claims].[TIN] = [Participating].[TIN] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr11] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr11].[Apr11_NYS_CODE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_CODE]  
  WHERE [Claims].[BeginningDOS] BETWEEN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_EFFECTIVE DATE] AND [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_END DATE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_CODE]    
  WHERE [Claims].[BeginningDOS] BETWEEN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_EFFECTIVE DATE] AND [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_END DATE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NY Medicare] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NY Medicare].[MEDICARE_HCPCS CODE]  
  WHERE [Claims].[Zone] = [NY Medicare].[MEDICARE_ZONE]
```

Answer (score 1):

A SQL query only has one `where` clause.  You should change these conditions to be part of the `on` conditions:

```
FROM ( ( ( ( ( ( [Claims]  
LEFT JOIN [BillType] ON [Claims].[Bill_Type] = [BillType].[BillType_Bill Type Key] )  
LEFT JOIN [PlaceofService] ON [Claims].[Place_of_Service] = [PlaceofService].[POS_Place of Service] )  
LEFT JOIN [Participating] ON [Claims].[TIN] = [Participating].[TIN] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr11] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr11].[Apr11_NYS_CODE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_CODE]  
  AND [Claims].[BeginningDOS] BETWEEN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_EFFECTIVE DATE] AND [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Jan12].[Jan12_NYS_END DATE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_CODE]    
  AND [Claims].[BeginningDOS] BETWEEN [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_EFFECTIVE DATE] AND [NYS Medicaid Fee Schedule Apr13].[Apr13_NYS_END DATE] )  
LEFT JOIN [NY Medicare] ON [Claims].[FivedigitProcCode] = [NY Medicare].[MEDICARE_HCPCS CODE]  
  AND [Claims].[Zone] = [NY Medicare].[MEDICARE_ZONE]
```